# Excluding words in sentimentr

Tags: r

How do you drop multiple terms from the sentimentr dictionary?

For example, the words "please" and "advise" are associated with positive sentiment, but I do not want those particular words to influence my analysis.

I've figured out a way with the following script to exclude 1 word but need to exclude many more:

```
mysentiment<- lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers_rinker[x != "please"]

mytext <- c(
  'Hello, We are looking to purchase this material for a part we will be making, but your site doesnt state that this is RoHS complaint. Is it possible that its just not listed as such online, but it actually is RoHS complaint? Please advise. '
)

sentiment_by(mytext, polarity_dt = mysentiment)
extract_sentiment_terms(mytext,polarity_dt = mysentiment)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can subset the mysentiment data.table. Just create a vector of the words you don't want included and use it to subset.

```
mysentiment<- lexicon::hash_sentiment_jockers_rinker
words_to_exclude <- c("please", "advise")
mysentiment <- mysentiment [!x %in% words_to_exclude]
```